# Can SKPaymentQueue process multiple in app purchases at a time?

Tags: swift, storekit

I have no trouble purchasing items one at a time, but when I add two items to the queue in quick succession with `SKPaymentQueue.default().add()`, the second transaction is never called by `updatedTransactions()`. Debugging the queue contents shows that the second transaction is in the queue, with a `transactionState` of `.purchasing`.

Relevant Code:

```
// AppDelegate.swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let inAppPurchasesHelper = InAppPurchasesHelper()
        inAppPurchasesHelper.setAsTransactionObserver()
    }
}

// InAppPurchasesHelper.swift
class InAppPurchasesHelper : NSObject, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    func setAsTransactionObserver() {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    }


    func buy(productIdentifier: String) {
        let product = // product retrieval from app data model using productIdentifier
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(SKPayment(product: product))
        print("Added \(item.productIdentifier) to SKPaymentQueue.")
    }


    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionState.purchased:
                print("Purchased \(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)")
                downloadTransaction(transaction)
                break

            case SKPaymentTransactionState.failed:
                print("Failed \(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)")
                failedTransaction(transaction)
                break

            case SKPaymentTransactionState.restored:
                print("Restored \(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)")
                downloadTransaction(transaction)
                break

            case SKPaymentTransactionState.deferred:
                print("Deferred \(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)")
                break

            case SKPaymentTransactionState.purchasing:
                print("Purchasing \(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)")
                break
            }
        }
    }


    func downloadTransaction(_ transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        if let downloads = transaction.downloads as [SKDownload]? {
            SKPaymentQueue.default().start(downloads)
        }
    }


    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedDownloads downloads: [SKDownload]) {
        for download in downloads {
            switch (download.state) {
            case .waiting:
                break

            case .active:
                break

            case .finished:
                finishedDownload(download)
                break

            case .failed:
                failedDownload(download)
                break

            case .cancelled:
                failedDownload(download)

            case .paused:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Up voted, because it seems like it should. But consider - it's a queue, meaning something like FIFO (first in first out). And you've not shown us your code. (Probably like me, you claim your code works "first time every time"! Just kidding.) Maybe the issue isn't with `SKPaymentQueue`, but in how you've coded for it. Please, show us your StoreKit code.

Comment: @dfd Of course. I added all of the relevant code to the issue.

Comment: Your code looks good - it's pretty much identical to mine. (I don't allow multiple transactions, which is really why I up-voted.) If I could, I'd add a second up vote. It *feels* to me like the queue is correct, but you aren't receiving the second transaction in a timely way - which (to me) isn't right. I've never placed a bounty on something on SO yet, but you might force me to do it!

Comment: @dfd Haha yeah, it certainly is strange behavior. I've given the queue plenty of time to call `updatedTransactions()`, but it just never happens. I worked around the issue by implementing my own FIFO that waits until each transaction is complete before adding the next payment to `SKPaymentQueue`. Interesting note - if I add the next payment to `SKPaymentQueue` after `updatedTransactions()` but before the first payment finishes downloading, then `updatedDownloads()` never gets called for the second item. Very strange.