# how to buy multiple products at once using the flutter in_app_purchase package

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am using the flutter `in_app_purchase` package found here https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase and have implemented it into my app according to the google code lab found here https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases#0.

### Problem:

I would like to have a user checkout with multiple non-consumable products at once. I am able to create a `List<PurchaseParam>` containing the products a user would like to checkout with but I am unable to find any functions in the `in_app_purchase` package that will allow me to handle multiple product payments at once.

Does anyone know of a way to use in_app_purchases to perform multiple purchases at once? (Looking for a function name or some reference material to get me on the right track).

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank You!

Comment: Can you create multiple individual items on the backend to encompass the combinations of purchases you need? It could be a less than great experience for the user to have to individually approve every item.

Comment: I have done that already. The problem is that I can't find a way using ```in_app_purchase``` to pass the combination of items to the google/apple billing api's.

Comment: Perhaps an example will help clarify. Say you have two products, A and B. On the backend, create three entries: `product_A`, `product_B`, and `products_A_and_B`. Then, as far as the user (and the API) is concerned, there is ever only one "purchase." Of course, for the `products_A_and_B` product, you would need to fulfill both products A and B after the purchase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 13 January 2023, the [in_app_purchase package](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) does not provide an interface for purchasing multiple items at once (aside from quantity, in the case of purchasing multiple of the *same* item).

However, while I've not personally ever attempted this, it *appears* that perhaps, at least for iOS, you *may* be able to simply call [`buyNonConsumable()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/in_app_purchase/latest/in_app_purchase/InAppPurchase/buyNonConsumable.html) multiple times to add multiple products to the payment queue. Be aware that doing so will require the purchase UI and user confirmation for each individual item. I have no idea how this might be handled on Android.

References

- `in_app_purchase` [source code for iOS](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/d607cd91049d1fe5127cb9e427d2ed7c03462fda/packages/in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase_storekit/lib/src/in_app_purchase_storekit_platform.dart#L70-L84)
- `in_app_purchase` [source code for Android](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/d607cd91049d1fe5127cb9e427d2ed7c03462fda/packages/in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase_android/lib/src/in_app_purchase_android_platform.dart#L126-L143)
- [Can SKPaymentQueue process multiple in app purchases at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45867754/3558355)
- [Purchasing multiple consumables at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38817449/3558355)